# Second table columns inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not able to select  columns as I am getting SQL command not properly ended error

```
(
  select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE 
  from (
    select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE
    from employee_1 
  ) myemployee
) join ( 
   ( select mobile_1.mobile_no,mobile_1.status  
     from mobile_1 
) as mymobile ) on myemployee.mobile_no = mymobile.mobile_no
```

Thanks in advance. If this is work i will apply it in my project.

Comment: Please format you sql code. Placing the code like this makes it a lot harder for other people to read. Try to check the () if are all placed.

Comment: **Way** too many useless parentheses in your SQL. The statement can be simplified to `select ... from employee_1 join mobile_1 on ..`

Comment: Formatted code                                                                               select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE from 
   (
     select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE from employee_1 ) myemployee
    )
join
  ( 
    ( select mobile_1.mobile_no,mobile_1.status  from mobile_1 )  
   ) mymobile
on 
   myemployee.mobile_no = mymobile.mobile_no

Comment: can u please compy this sql code into notepad or something please

Comment: (
  select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE 
  from (
    select mobile_no,SIM_NO,START_DATE,END_DATE
    from employee_1 
  ) myemployee
) join
  (  ( select mobile_1.mobile_no,mobile_1.status  from mobile_1 ) mymobile )
    on myemployee.mobile_no = mymobile.mobile_no

Answer (score 0):

This one might be better:

```
SELECT mobile_no,
       sim_no,
       start_date,
       end_date
  FROM (SELECT mobile_no,
               sim_no,
               start_date,
               end_date
          FROM employee_1) myemployee
       JOIN
       (SELECT mobile_1.mobile_no, mobile_1.status FROM mobile_1) mymobile
          ON myemployee.mobile_no = mymobile.mobile_no;
```

**[EDIT, based on a_horse's comment]**

```
SELECT e.mobile_no,
       e.sim_no,
       e.start_date,
       e.end_date
  FROM employee_1 e JOIN mobile_1 m ON m.mobile_no = e.mobile_no
```

Comment: The derived tables are useless. That can be simplified to `select ... from employee_1 join mobile_1 on ..`

Comment: Hey thnx.. error SQL command not properly ended is not appearing but column ambiguously defined is coming now. what it means

Comment: @Littlefoot I have solved it thank you very much for the first error. i have put extra ( bracket for very first query. i got it from your hint. thnx again

Comment: Absolutely, @a_horse; I was just "fixing" what was wrong with the original code. Now I've edited the message and added its simplified version.

Comment: You're welcome, @Mayur